# Finding points of a triangle with distance constraints

Tags: geometry

I have a geometry problem that is a bit more difficult than I am prepared for. I am trying to model a system in python. I have a triangle representing a rigid body that is suspended by two bodies (represented by constant length lines that can rotate) and one body that can change length and rotation around a pivot point. The triangle is of constant size and proportions, but its position and orientation can change.

The result of the system I am trying to describe is a 6 side shape that is not guaranteed to be concave or convex. Going clockwise I have labelled these points A,B,C,D,E,F. **I am looking to determine the coordinate of points C,D,E given the distance between A and C as a parameter.**

Sides: **AB**, BC, **CD**, **DE**, **EF**, FA. (sides with constant length are in bold)

Points with constant distance: DB, BF, CE,

Points with variable distance: CB, EB, CF, AE

Points that can move: C,D,E

Points that cannot move: A, B, F

[image: Drawing and example of scenario]

Please ask any questions you may have about this scenario. Pretty good chance that i left some things open to interpretation.

Happy New Year's Everyone!